# editing variables for a compiled c# application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# project which includes a web browser

I need to create another c# project which edits the Uri for the web browser

it is stored as a public variable
I tried spliting it to to files "before the variable and after" and then write all bytes using Binary Writer

it worked only when the length of the string is the same

so i tried editing the byte before the string which i saw represents the length but nothing worked

hope someone can help me

Comment: Yeah, this won't work. Why do you need to do this? There is undoubtedly a better solution to your problem than editing the raw bits of a compiled binary.

Comment: I want to share this porject without sharing the source

Comment: So do what everyone else does. Arrange for the URI to be passed as a command-line parameter, read from a configuration file, etc.

Comment: Why not read the Uri from a file, then, or have it as a parameter?

Comment: Isn't there a way to edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are overwriting with shorter string, you can fill unused bytes with spaces. `WebBrowser` should handle this. Don't forgot about encoding.